# setTimeout in function that is continually called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is called when a user drags with the mouse. What the function does is not relevant but it is called `loadTiles();`

What I want is for the function to be called every 1000ms during user drag. However, if I do the following, the setTimeout will be started continually throughout the drag:

```
window.ontouchmove = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){ loadTiles(); },1000);
};
```

Is there a way to have the setTimeout actually count down the 1000ms uninterrupted and keep resetting to count again like `setInterval`?

Comment: This article has some good tips on debouncing events and optimizing setTimeout http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/#an-example

Comment: You might be looking for set interval

Comment: why not use setInterval?

Comment: Do you want to do this forever after a drag, or just until the user hasn't dragged anything for a given amount of time, and what if the user doesn't drag for a second, should it be aborted etc.

Comment: The loadTiles() function will be called ontouchend anyway. I just want it to also happen every 1000ms during ontouchmove if the user is for some reason taking their sweet time to drag.

Comment: @Mahan because the setInterval would be continually called as the user drags so it would keep creating a new call for loadTiles() also

Comment: What you are looking for is called "throttling" and there are a couple of questions regarding this already: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+throttle+function.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks. Always good to learn some new terminology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a Boolean variable to see if its been run or not.

```
var isrun=false;
window.ontouchmove = function(){
if(isrun==false){
isrun=true;
setTimeout(function(){ loadTiles(); },1000);
}
};
```

then in your loadTiles function set isrun back to false at the end

Comment: yeh that's what I was looking for! I've actually done this before but couldn't remember how to do it. Thanks bud

Comment: use `setInterval` (*and clear it when done*) or reset the `isrun` flag inside the callback..

Comment: yeh that's it. Answer needs slightly amending to include isrun=false inside the setTimeout for the loop to continue. Works perfectly with that.

Comment: um, wouldn't you want to set it back to false when it ran so it would be able to run again?

Comment: You set it back to false after the function has run so in the loadTiles function. OP your welcome, if this was it please mark as answer :)